# Hiding a div using multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have 4 select Yes/No boxes that I want to show/hide. The else statement below works but I only want to hide the div it's already showing (CSS for `.hidden` is `{display:none}`). Do I need to build a separate function?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#questions').change(function() {
        var q1Val = $('#q1 :selected').val();
        var q2Val = $('#q2 :selected').val();
        var q3Val = $('#q3 :selected').val();
        var q4Val = $('#q4 :selected').val();

        //alert(selectVal);
        if (q1Val == "No" && q2Val == "No" && q3Val == "No" && q4Val == "No" ) {
             $(".hidden").show( "slide" );
             //updated code to use show()
        }
        else {
            $(".hidden").hide( "slide" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why `toggle`? why not `show`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the code is actually `show` now, but the issue is with the `hide` portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:visible` in the selector:

```
$(".hidden:visible").hide( "slide" );
```

Not that I see the point of this too much, simply put the `$(".hidden").hide( "slide" );` statement as the very first part of your code, that way it just hides it regardless and shows the proper one with the change logic.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. (I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes when SO lets me!)

Answer (score 1):

What you are now saying in code is:

If all options are no, hide them. I don't think that's what you want to achieve?
if so, use || as operator.

Comment: What i understand of you code, it says if all options are no, or am i missing a part. sorry if i am confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should **give a common class to all the select boxes** `.sel_box` and then do something like this :

```
$('.sel_box').change(function() {
```